# Unable to install worklight-analytics.ear in WAS 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

MFP 6.3
WebSphere App Server 8.5.5
Server1 full profile

Using the WAS admin console I try to install the worklight-analytics ear file.  I select the local repository and locate the ear file.   After locating the file I select next, but the installation process simply hangs at this point, and does not continue to the next step of the install process which is to select detailed, or fast-path install.   I increased the transaction timeout (20 min) for the WAS server, but that had no impact, and the install process continued to hang.  I checked the WAS logs and found no issues reported.  As a confirmation I located other EAR files and was able to successfully move through the install process.

Appreciate any ideas why the EAR installation would hang.

Comment: I abandoned installing the  EAR, and now attempted to install the the individual WARs. worklight-analytics.war file which appears to have installed OK.  When I try to install the worklight-analytics-service.war the installation activity hangs once I've identified that image to install.

Answer (score 1):

No issues were logged in the WAS logs, but due to the size of the WAR I tried increasing the JVM Heap max to 512, and the war now installs.